# 500 error - source file [/var/w/config/settings.ini.cfm] is not a file

Tags: docker, jelastic, lucee, mura

1. Installed MuraCMS 7.1 using docker image with MySQL 5.7 and Lucee 5 at Jelastic cloud
2. The setup completed, but `index.cfm` throws a Lucee runtime error with the message *source file [/var/w/config/settings.ini.cfm] is not a file*
   [image: Error Message]

Can any suggest how to resolve the error?

Comment: We successfully installed the latest and 7.1 tags of MuraCMS. Works fine. As far as we can see you reports about /var/w/config/settings.ini.cfm, which actually doesn't exists. Correct path should be /var/www/config/settings.ini.cfm. Please, check once again and let us know.

Comment: latest image solved the issue.